# Python: Set many variables to the same value – with automatic count of number of variables

Tags: python

I want to create a lot of variables, all containing the same value.

Currently, I do this:

```
foo, bar, qaxx, spat = ("1Value4All",)*4
```

I would like to keep the code footprint at a minimum (one line here), but at the same time it's troublesome if there are many variables, because I have to assign the number of variables (`*4`) manually.

Can this be done *without manual count* of the number of variables – instead automatically assigning it to `*4`?

---

If the variables could be placed in a list, the number if items in that list could be iterated. But something like this is not possible because the variables become referenced before assignment.

```
my_variables = [foo, bar, qaxx, spat, dung, polo]

for v in my_variables:
    v = "1Value4All"
```

---

**Edit**: The data types for the variables will always be `str` or `None`. 
*(Not lists, dicts, sets.)*

Comment: foo = bar = qaxx = spat = "1Value4All"

Comment: Be aware that this does NOT create 4 separate copies of the value.  It creates _one_ copy, bound to four names.

Comment: @JohnGordon Ah – no, that's not what I want. I want to create many different objects, incidentally containing the same thing.

Comment: Beware: you __should__ not need "dynamic variable names" much less dynamic variable count in any programming pattern: probably you just need to use a dictionary instead.

Comment: @JohnGordon why does it matter? Strings are immutable anyway

Comment: @JamesBuck because maybe this is a stripped-down version of his real code, which _doesn't_ use strings.

Comment: If "the data will be `None` and strings", as you (the OP) wrote, there is no problem with using the `(value,)*n` method since everything is immutable.

Comment: If all values are immutable, I wonder why the need for many names.

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty neat trick, thanks for sharing.  I can't really think of a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain all the variables together in one line.

```
foo = bar = qaxx = spat = "1Value4All"
```

Edit: Below you state your data is either string or NoneType. This would work for both.

```
>>> foo = bar = None
>>> type(foo); type(bar)
<type 'NoneType'>
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> foo = bar = "1Value4All"
>>> type(foo); type(bar)
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I also want to allow them to be `None` (a non-iterable?)

Comment: @Winterflags: Same thing. `foo = bar = qaxx = spat = None`.

Comment: What type is the data? This will work for strings or numbers or None but not lists or dicts or sets.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist The data will be `None` and `str`. (Not lists, dicts, sets).

Comment: Why wouldn't the assignment work for container objects? It would work just fine, though they would all get a reference to the same object.

Comment: There's no iteration going on here. `None` will work, and so will any other value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple equal signs on the same line:

```
foo = bar = qaxx = spat = "1Value4All"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a default dictionary, that will create a new value for a key whenever you want it. Then you should use values from that dictionary - not as stand alone variables. Variable names are supposed to be hard coded in your program - if names or quantity are varying, you should be using a dictionary and accessing your values through keys, which are meant to be dynamic anyway:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> data = defaultdict(lambda: None)
>>> data["foo"], data["bar"]
>>> data.keys()
dict_keys(['foo', 'bar'])

>>>[data[key]  for key in "foo bar baz fnord blip blargh".split()]
>>> data.keys()
dict_keys(['fnord', 'bar', 'foo', 'blargh', 'baz', 'blip'])
```

I you really need to update variables, you can get global variables as easy as in:

```
>>> globals().update(data)
>>> bar
>>> fnord is None
True
```

This does not work for local variables  - to update those you have to pip install  `extradict` from PIP and use it's MapGetter context manager. (https://github.com/jsbueno/extradict) .

```
$ pip install extradict
$ python
...
>>> from extradict import MapGetter
>>> with MapGetter(default="1Value4All") as tmp:
...    from tmp import foo, bar, baz, qaxx, spat
...
>>> foo
'1Value4All'
```